# Question related to asymptotic equivalence and possibly regularly varying functions

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, slowly-varying-functions

Let $f(n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be a function such that $f(n) \sim n^{-1/2}$. Let $\delta \in (0,1)$. I want to prove that $$ \sum_{j \leq \lfloor \delta n \rfloor} f(j) \sim 2 \delta n \, f(\lfloor \delta n \rfloor). $$
I am fairly lost here. I thought about using that $f(n)$ is a regularly varying function, but got nowhere. Any ideas why this is true? (The parentheses $\lfloor \ \rfloor$ are supposed to mean taking the next lower integer, e.g. $\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor = 2$.)

Comment: Use integral approximations.

Comment: @openspace Could you elaborate? Writing for instance $$ \sum_{j \leq \lfloor \delta n \rfloor} f(j) \approx \int_0^{\lfloor \delta n \rfloor} f(j) dj $$ does not really make sense to me and I don't see how this would even help. In particular, as $f(n)$ behaves like $n^{-1/2}$ only for large $n$.

Comment: Now you can use that $f(j) \sim j^{-1/2}$

Comment: @openspace So, $$ \sum_{ j \leq \lfloor \delta n \rfloor} f(j) \overset{?}{\sim} \int_0^{\lfloor \delta n \rfloor } j^{-1/2} dj = 2 (\delta n)^{1/2} = 2\delta n f(\lfloor \delta n \rfloor) ?$$ I am not entirely convinced that the first relation (marked with an "?") is in fact true. Could you argue, why it holds true (if I have in fact done the steps that you wanted me to do)?